# Read a particular line from file and `strcmp` the character from that line fails in c code

Tags: c

I thought to not to ask this simple question about file handing, but I am not getting why I Am getting this error.

I have a input file.txt which has dump from the code run -

```
**** input.txt ****
frame_number:0 | x:541 ## y:8 @idx:0
frame_number:1 | x:51 ## y:8 @idx:0
...
frame_number:50 | x:579 ## y:18 @idx:1
...
frame_number:100 | x:593 ## y:21 @idx:2
...
frame_number:1000 | x:613 ## y:10 @idx:3
...
```

I have written a code for reading the same content and wants to read frame number, x and y coordinates for every index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit()
#include <string.h>


static const char* input_cornersfilename     = "input.txt" ;
static const char* output_filename           = "output.txt" ;

int readFrameNumber(char *line)
{
    char frame_number[4];
    char readContent[6];
    strncpy(readContent, line+13, 6);

    int i = 0;
    int result;

    while(i < 6) {

        result = strcmp(&readContent[i], "|");

        if(result !=0) {

            frame_number[i] = readContent[i];

        } else {

            break;

        }

        i++;
    }

    return atoi(frame_number);
}

int readXCord(char *line)
{
    char xCord[4];
    char readContent1[15]; //= "500 | x : 541 ## y:8 @idx:0";
    strncpy(readContent1, line+13, 14);

    int i = 0;
    int result;

    char cmpchar[] = "x";

    while(i < 14) {

        result = strcmp(&readContent1[i], cmpchar);

        if(result == 0) {
            strcpy(xCord, &readContent1[i]);
            xCord[i] = readContent1[i];

        } else {
            printf("i;%d | readContent[i];%c\n", i, readContent1[i]);
            //break;

        }

        i++;
    }

    return atoi(xCord);
}

int readYCord(char *line)
{
    char yCord[4];
    char readContent1[15]; //= "500 | x : 541 ## y:8 @idx:0";
    strncpy(readContent1, line+13, 20);

    int i = 0;
    int result;

    char cmpchar[] = "y";

    while(i < 14) {

        result = strcmp(&readContent1[i], cmpchar);

        if(result == 0) {
            strcpy(xCord, &readContent1[i]);
            xCord[i] = readContent1[i];

        } else {
            printf("i;%d | readContent[i];%c\n", i, readContent1[i]);
            //break;

        }

        i++;
    }

    return atoi(yCord);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr1, *fptr2;
    char c;

    // Open one file for reading
    fptr1 = fopen(input_cornersfilename, "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", input_cornersfilename);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Open another file for writing
    fptr2 = fopen(output_filename, "w");
    if (fptr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", output_filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    int frameIdx = 0, x_cord = 0, y_cord = 0;
    char frame_number[40];
    char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
    {
        printf("Line read:%s", line);

        frameIdx = readFrameNumber(line);
        x_cord = readXCord(line);
        y_cord = readYCord(line);

        printf("frame_number:%d | x_cord:%d | y_cord:%d \n", frameIdx, x_cord, y_cord);
    }

    printf("\nContents copied to %s", input_cornersfilename);

    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

1. Here my `strcmp` is not comparing the the string with the required character strings and My code is not doing as per the expectation.
2. Can any one suggest me some other method to read `frame_number`, `x` and `y` coordinates from this **input.txt**

Can any one tell me my mistake in my code.

Comment: `strcmp` doesn't compare just one character. It would seem you want something like `if (readContent[i] == '|') { ... }`

Comment: @RetiredNinja, with this logic I am getting this error. **error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer**

Comment: Be sure to note the single quotes used for a character literal `'|'`. Since I can't see what you tried that's my best guess.

Comment: and also **warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]**          **if(readContent[i] != "|")**

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thanks you.Its working with single quote. Can you suggest any other way do write the code for above scenario in c or c++ **Question** **(2)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here: You fail to add a terminating null character to the strings `frame_number`, `xCord` and `yCord`; you never write anything to your output file; and you've made the entire process unnecessarily complicated. You can completely eliminate the functions `readFrameNumer`, `readXCord`, and `readYCord`, and make the loop in `main` look like this:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
{
    printf("Line read:%s", line);
    if (sscanf(line, "frame_number:%d | x:%d ## y:%d",
            &frameIdx, &x_cord, &y_cord) != 3) {
        /* handle error */
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("frame_number:%d | x_cord:%d | y_cord:%d \n",
            frameIdx, x_cord, y_cord);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is more cleaner solution. Because of less points to me , I can not click on accept the answer.

Comment: @urmilasontakke: you can accept the answer regardless of how much rep you have. Your lack of rep affects your being able to upvote the answer, but you can and should accept it if it meets your needs